# How to replace elements in a series with matching words in a dictionary (Python)

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, key

I'm trying to create a column that uses customer name to designate a type by looking at keywords in a dictionary.

If a customer name matches the keys, then append a new column with the key.
Ex. Oak Sheriff's Office would be POLICE as an entry in a new column

Here is my code:

```
keywords = {} 
key_dict['POLICE'] = ['police', 'sheriff', 'safety']
key_dict['FIRE'] = ['fire', 'rescue']


for cust in renewals['customer name']:
    for word in keywords:
        for key in keywords[word]:
            if key in cust:
                df = df.append({'Type':word}, ignore_index=True)
                break
        break
```

I can't get the loop to stop iterating after it finds a keyword so I end up with more rows than I started with.  I'm sure there is a better way than creating three loops but I don't know how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest way is to extract this loop in a function and use `return`. `break` by nature only breaks out of the innermost loop.

```
for cust in renewals['customer name']:
    my_func(cust)


def my_func(cust):
    for word in keywords:
        for key in keywords[word]:
            if key in cust:
                df = df.append({'Type':word}, ignore_index=True)
                return
```

If using a function is out of the question, you'd need to carry a variable e.g.

```
for cust in renewals['customer name']:
    key_found = False
    for word in keywords:
        for key in keywords[word]:
            if key in cust:
                df = df.append({'Type':word}, ignore_index=True)
                key_found = True
                break
        if key_found:
            break
```

Comment: returning a value end the function though.  I need it to loop through each row in the df and assign a customer type to each customer.  Maybe I need to have a function within the first loop?

Comment: Indeed, that would work

Comment: I modified the example to reflect